# Is it bad practice to have negative CSS rules?

Tags: css

I always feel terrible whenever am forced to do something like this

```css
.post-excerpt {
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

But does having negative values in css rules have any detrimental effects in anyway?

Comment: ahah, Im sometimes asking me the same thing but I would not consider this as a bad practice.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. However, if you happen to use them a lot you might want to look into your css a bit more in detail to see if you can somehow improve it overall :-)

Comment: exact same answer as the duplicate lol

Comment: hah, you are right ^^ - will mark it as duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

This is especially true. It’s because of not understanding negative margins properly that it got its hackish image. It only becomes a hack if you use it to fix an error you made elsewhere.

[Reference](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)